# Trying to force image uploads with Presigned POST: Content-Type policy fails when uploading images

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm using the Ruby AWS SDK to generate a Presigned Post object to allow users to upload images directly to S3 (you know, the standard workflow). Here's how I'm generating the presigned post object:

```
def s3_presigned_post
  S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(
    key: aws_key,
    content_type_starts_with: 'image/',
    success_action_status: '201',
    acl: 'public-read')
end
```

The `content_type_starts_with: 'image/'` part was pulled directly from the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html) (cmd-f "Field Starts With").

When I try to subsequently upload images using the fields returned from this object, I get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image"]</Message>
  <RequestId>[redacted]</RequestId>
  <HostId>[redacted]</HostId>
</Error>
```

The upload succeeds if I remove the `content_type_starts_with` constraint. In Paw, I verified that the image is indeed being uploaded with a Content-Type of `image/jpeg`:

[image]

Similarly, making a web form and submitting it gives me the same exact response:

```
<form action="https://reel-guiding-development.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="[redacted]" />
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201" />
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="[redacted]=" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-credential" value="[redacted]" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-date" value="20160226T143447Z" />
  <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-signature" value="dfe48736cdf600f90181019792835c991df089a4c8c1942fe40c8ed1fa11a80e" />

  <input type="file" name="file" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great!

Comment: *"When using starts with, the form must contain a field where the user can specify the value."*  (or a hidden field)... you don't have `<input name="Content-Type" ...>`  in your form.

Comment: Should've specified in the original post that I tried that too – no luck with Paw or with the HTML form.

Comment: Never mind – got it to work with the HTML form! However, I can now upload any file I want as long as I have the Content-Type field set to `image/___`. I was under the impression that AWS would manually check the MIME type of the uploaded file. Any ideas on how to restrict more rigorously?